# Allow stringstream and outstream as parameter

Tags: c++, stream

I'm trying to write a function that writes information to a stream. I need to be able to pass it either a stringstream or an ostream. I tried declaring the function with `F(std::ios* out)`, but then later when I use the `<<` operator to write to it, I get this error: `error: no match for operator<<`. How should I be declaring the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [*c++ references*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29)

```
void F(std::ostream& out)
{
}
```

would do the trick; Note that this will assume `char` streams, otherwise:

```
template <typename Char/*=char*/, typename Traits/*=std::char_traits<CharT> */>
    void F(std::basic_ostream<Char, Traits>& os)
{
}
```

Comment: There is also a `Traits` template parameter.

Comment: @K-ballo: duly noted; now where was it that I think I saw default template arguments might be allowed for functions in c++11?

Comment: In C++11 default template arguments are allowed, but there is no need to use them here since the arguments should always match those of the stream.

Comment: @sehe : [Here's a start](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#226).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should probably pass a *reference* to the stream, because otherwise you'll have to write `(*out)<<` to make the insertion operator work correctly (it works on streams, not on *pointer* to streams).

But more importantly, `std::ios` is just one of the base classes of the streams, namely the one that contains members of the IO classes that are not dependent on template parameters.

If you want to receive a generic output stream you should accept a reference to `std::ostream` (for `char`-based streams) or to `std::wostream` (for `wchar_t`-based streams); if you want to go generic you should make your function template for `char_type` and `char_traits` to allow all the variations of the `std::basic_ostream class` (notice however that writing character type-independent code often is not simple at all, and if you don't need it it may not be worth the effort - better to use some `TCHAR`-like strategy).

So, probably what you want is:

```
F(std::ostream & out)
```

(for input streams, it's exactly the same, but with `std::istream`/`std::wistream`/`std::basic_istream`)

Answer (score 2):

`stringstream` *is* an `ostream`. Generic I/O functions should generally take either `ostream` or `istream` as a reference.

```
void fun(std::ostream& out);
```

This will work with both `stringstream` and other `ostream` subclasses, like `fstream`.

Comment: _Generic_ I/O functions should take either `basic_ostream<>` or `basic_istream<>` as a reference, instead of restricting the stream's character and traits types.

Comment: @ildjarn: on the other hand, if you have to write any string `char_type`-independent IO quickly becomes a mess, and may not be worth the effort (`TCHAR`-like alternatives can be more easily implemented).